# select Output 5 block to release agents in order and once batch size condition satisfied

Tags: anylogic

I need to put a condition or action in the select output 5 block.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9gvy.png)

The model has select 5 output block, 5 batch blocks and 5 delays blocks. Each delay block has a delay of 105 hours. I need to control the movement of agents to fill each delay in sequence. If one delay becomes available, then select output 5 block will release agents to the available delay.
For example, select output 5 block control the release of agents from each exit based on a condition.  Condition one will check if batch capacity filled (see image attached). Therefore, it will start to release agents from exit two to fill up batch 1. Once batch one capacity completed, the select 5 block will start to release agents from exit 2 to fill batch 2 capacity and so on.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGqUY.png)

Can I do the above using select output 5 block?

Comment: Hi Zag. I don't understand your output conditions. Are agents going through this process more than once?

Comment: Hi buggaby, Select output 5 block will be controlled sequentially based on the patch size being filled respectively. So if patch 1 linked to exit 1 filled then exit 2 will be activated to release agents to patch 2 and other exits will be deactivated etc. the processes is repetitive with respect to the number of agents from source .

Comment: What do you mean by batch 1 "linked to exit 1 filled"? As soon as the batch is filled, it should push a new agent type into the service block and then it will be empty again. Also, "batch2.batchSize" just returns the size of the batch, not the number of entities waiting to be batched. You can help by updating your question with a worked example to be more clear. For example, "I have these 5 entities come in and go hear, then a 6th one comes in while these 5 are in the service queue and this 6th one should go to batch3" or something.

Comment: Just edited the question. Thanks. Please consider provided images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to select the output based on which batches have available space. The problem is that batches aren't really ever full, because as soon as they get, say, 5 agents, it immediately makes a batch and passes that new batched agent onto the next process block. So really, you should be polling the queue in the delay block. For example, the exit condition for the first output (into `batch`) could be `Curing_Drying.size() < Curing_Drying.capacity`. This means that there is capacity in that delay for more batched agents and you can continue sending stuff down that line.

This also means that the `batch` line will be used more than, say, `batch4`, since that one will only be used whenever all other `Curing_Drying` delays are full. And if that one fills up and there's no space anywhere else, you'll get an error saying "An agent was not able to leave the port...".